# window.location affected by escape key?

Tags: javascript

I have a timer to refresh the page, and it's working:

```
updateCountdown = function() {
    if (Variables.Seconds == Infinity) {
    } else if (Variables.Seconds == 0) {
        $countdown.text('Bam!');
        window.location.replace(Variables.PageName);
    } else {
        $countdown.text(Variables.Seconds--);
        setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
    }
};
```

Then I have this:

```
document.onkeydown=function(e) {

    if (e.which==27) {
        Variables.Seconds = 0;
        updateCountdown();
    }
};
```

When I press escape, then $countdown.text says 'Bam!', but the page does not refresh like it does whenever Variables.Seconds normally decrements to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to do `return false;` after you call updateCountdown(); to cancel the default action of Escape.

```
   document.onkeydown=function(e) {

        if (e.which==27) {
            Variables.Seconds = 0;
            updateCountdown();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

If you are using other javascript libraries [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) might be of help.

Comment: e.preventDefault()!  What was I thinking!

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn I have learned this the hard way (wasted days on a similar issue).